# ¿Cómo implementar las configuraciones de Quasar?

Tags: vue.js, quasar, i18n

Estoy intentando implementar internacionalización en mi proyecto. Estoy usando [quasar](https://quasar.dev/options/app-internationalization#setup-manually), [Vuei18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) y [vue 3 con `<script setup>`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html).

Este es mi archivo *main.js*:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'
import quasarLang from 'quasar/lang/es'
import quasarConfig from './quasar.config.js'
import router from './routes/router.js'
import { createPinia, PiniaVuePlugin } from 'pinia'

// Import icon libraries
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons-outlined/material-icons-outlined.css'
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons-round/material-icons-round.css'
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons-sharp/material-icons-sharp.css'

// A few examples for animations from Animate.css:
import '@quasar/extras/animate/fadeIn.css'
import '@quasar/extras/animate/fadeOut.css'

// Import Quasar css
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'

import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App)
.use(Quasar, quasarConfig)
.use(createPinia())
.use(router)
.mount('#app')
```

Y este es mi *quasar.config.js*:

```
var countryCode = navigator.language;

const quasarConfig = {
  boot: [
    'i18n'
  ]
};

export default quasarConfig;
```

Pero al intentar utilizar la librería (

```
<template>
  {{ $t('welcome') }}
</template>

<script setup>
</script>
```

) no hace absolutamente nada. Y me devuelve "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.$t is not a function".

¿Cómo puedo implementar correctamente la internacionalización y además el objeto de configuración de quasar?